# no internet connection in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, internet-connection, dsl

I've disabled the network that connects to the internet. But I don't know how to enable it. How do I do it.

This is a lan, dsl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Control Panel
- View network status and tasks
- Left hand sidebar, click Change Adapter settings
- Right click adapter and click Enable